# Can I add 2 'types' to a form input element?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile to construct a search dialogue.
The input on the search is numerical so ideally I would like to add a 'type' of search and number.
Is this possible?
If not is there an easy work around?

Comment: i think you can't do this....

Comment: Interesting question (+1). It makes no sense in most cases for an input to have two types, but that's not the case for search. "search" could have been defined as a type qualifier rather than as a type in it's own right. Sadly it wasn't.

Comment: +1 Have to admit, I found this a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare the `type` twice, but you can use a **[pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp)**:

```
<input type="search" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

It's still experimental, so make sure to add an additional (jQuery and/or server-side) validation.

Comment: Will that display a numeric keyboard on a device?

Comment: @ShiftyThomas i don't think so, you've to test it. As i said, it's an experimental feature. If your main goal is to display a numeric keyboard, you better switch to `<input type="number">`, losing the "x" on the right which is the main feature of `type="search"`

Comment: I think that's going to have to be it, the front end usability of having a keyboard does over rule the need for the search boxes added functionality. I might at a later date style the input and add the 'x' button functionality.